# How to properly install latest Jabref?

Tags: launcher

I downloaded `JabRef-3.2.jar`. I can execute it from the command line:

```
java -jar JabRef-3.2.jar
```

which works fine. But I would like to have a Launcher in my start menu, if possible with an appropriate icon. How can I do this?

Note: I am running Xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: The JabRef team is working in on getting a snap running for JabRef. See [pull request](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/pull/2345#issuecomment-320210962). Installation: `sudo snap install jabref --edge --devmode`. Update: `sudo snap refresh jabref --edge --devmode`. There will be stable version as soon as a) JabRef 4.0 is released and b) this snap is considered stable. Any feedback and support is appreciated.

Comment: @koppor Good to know. Hope it gets out soon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, change directory

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then, open nano editor:

```
nano JabRef.desktop
```

Add the following to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=PATH TO YOUR ICON
Exec=java -jar /path/to/your/JabRef-3.2.jar
Name=NAME YOUR DESKTOP ICON
```

Then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> --> <kbd>Y</kbd> --> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It should create an icon for you to launch, just search for it in `Menu`.

Comment: Where can I get Jabref's icon?

Comment: Here are some [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=jabref+icon&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf2fT68KvKAhUFC44KHRr8CUMQsAQICw)

Comment: Download an ico  from there and save it to any folder. Its recommended to keep the icon anywhere except `/media/*` folder.

Comment: Yes it still works. If its gone, try checking the location. First run it from terminal to check if the command still works

Comment: OK! Glad it worked

Comment: What if I want to run a command like $ > jabref  ?

Comment: Nice answer, and I suceeded in creating my launcher icon. Nevertheless I still have two problems: first, unlike other icons, I need to __double__-click it, rather than simply clicking once to have JabRef open. Secondly, JabRef still does not apply in the "Open With" menu, and I do not know how to tell my system to use it regularly to open .bib files.

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy I had exactly the same concern. Please, review [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068956/164341) about how I solved this elegantly for both the desktop as the command line.

Answer (score 2):

## Desktop, File Browser & Command Line

Personally, I have created a `/home/bin` directory to keep scripts for occasions like this.

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/bin
```

Just make sure that for every user the directory `/home/bin` is accessible:

```
$ sudo chmod +rx /home/bin
```

Furthermore the new directory should be listed as `PATH="/home/bin:$PATH"` in the `~/.profile` file of every user or wherever `PATH` happens to be defined on your system.

Save below `bash` script as `jabref` in the newly created `/home/bin/` directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
INSTALLDIR='/home/opt/jabref'

# Run the latest version.
java -jar $(ls -1v $INSTALLDIR/JabRef*.jar |tail -n 1) $@ &
```

The `bash` script should be made executable with:

```
$ sudo chmod +x jabref
```

The script will open the latest version of `JabRef*.jav` previously saved in `/home/opt/jabref/` with **any yet existing** desktop launcher or any file browser integration. Simply typing `jabref` at the command line also works.

Comment: A little late, but this works great, even with the i3wm DE.