# Running Jab-Ref3.5.jar on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, java

I downloaded `JabRef-3.5.jar` and I'm trying to execute it from the command line as follows:

```
java -jar JabRef-3.5.jar
```

Just as it says in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721378/how-to-properly-install-latest-jabref).

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It says:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile JabRef-3.5.jar
```

Do I have to put the jarfile in a specific path to make it work?

Using Ubuntu 14.04.

---

Added information:

The .jar-file is in my "Downloads" directory. If I run

> java -jar ~/Downloads/JabRef-3.5.jar

it says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/sf/jabref/JabRefMain : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Do I need to install basic java-packages first?

Comment: Which is your working directory and where is that file?

Comment: the .jar-file is in ~/Downloads